# How to exclude e-mails that contain wrong TLDs

Tags: regex

I am not an expert on RegEx, but i need to somehow ignore e-mail addresses that end with certain wrong TLDs. Typically its gif, png etc.

How do i combine this so it ignores emails with `png` or `gif`.

Here is my expression:

```
[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+
```

In Python form:

```
re.findall(r'[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.[a-z]+', "this@test.com, this@test.png")
```

Fiddle:

http://refiddle.co/refiddles/55660c5b75622d4d8c800000

Comment: ...and what's the problem you're having?

Comment: and what is a "wrong" tld? Given that ICANN is handing out TLDs like candy, there's really no such thing as a "wrong" tld anymore.

Comment: I do not know how to combine it with a `and not` behaviour.

Comment: @MarcB https://publicsuffix.org

Comment: `png` is not exactly a TLD yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "Negative Lookahead" to exclude them:

```
[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+@[a-z0-9\.\-+_]+\.((?!png|gif)([a-z]+))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a waste of time trying to shoe-horn that check into a regex.  Just apply your initial regex and then filter out any "bad" domains afterwards as a secondary check.

FWIW, we exclude ".con" from our list of allowed email addresses, because users mistype .com as .con all the time.